# How do I produce a Kinesis Data Stream HashKey from a PartitionKey?

Tags: c#, md5, amazon-kinesis

I'm consuming data from a Kinesis Data Stream using a C# client. There are multiple instances of the C# client, one for each shard in the stream, each concurrently retrieves Kinesis Records using the [GetRecords](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_GetRecords.html) method.

The [PutRecords](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_PutRecords.html) call is being performed on an external system which is specifying an IMEI as the 'PartitionKey' value. The HashKey (and hence shard selection) is being performed by the KinesisClient using (from the docs) 'An MD5 hash function ... to map partition keys to 128-bit integer values and to map associated data records to shards using the hash key ranges of the shards'.

I have an external system update which is broadcasting IMEI related data to all of the running clients. My challenge is that I need to determine which client is processing the data for the IMEI, hence I need to apply the same 'MD5 hash function' as the KinesisClient is applying to the data. My intention is then to compare the hash to the HashKey range of the shard the client is processing, allowing the client to determine whether it is interested in the IMEI data, or not.

I've tried to work this out and have this code:

```
byte[] hash;
string imei = "123456789012345";
using (MD5 md5 = MD5.Create()) {
    hash = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(imei));
}
Console.WriteLine(new BigInteger(hash));
```

However, this gives me a negative value and my shard HashKey ranges are positive.

I really need the C# code which the KinesisClient is using to turn a PartitionKey into a HashKey, but I can't find it. Can anyone help me to work this out please?

---

**UPDATE:** I'm making progress after finding the links I mentioned in the comments below. My code currently looks like this:

```
private static MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();
private static List<BigInteger> powersOfTen = null;
private static BigInteger MAXHASHKEY =BigInteger.Parse("340282366920938463463374607431768211455");

public String CreateExplicitHashKey(String partitionKey) {
    byte[] pkDigest = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(partitionKey));
    byte[] hashKeyBytes = new byte[16];

    for (int i = 0; i < pkDigest.Length; i++) {
        hashKeyBytes[16 - i - 1] = (byte)((int)pkDigest[i] & 0xFF);
    }
    BigInteger hashKey = new BigInteger(hashKeyBytes, true, false);

    if (powersOfTen == null) {
        powersOfTen = new List<BigInteger>();
        powersOfTen.Add(1);
        for (BigInteger i = 10; i < MAXHASHKEY; i *= i) {
            powersOfTen.Add(i);
        }
    }
    return BuildString(hashKey, powersOfTen.Count - 1).ToString().TrimStart('0');
}

private static string BuildString(BigInteger n, int m) {
    if (m == 0) return n.ToString();
    BigInteger remainder;
    BigInteger quotient = BigInteger.DivRem(n, powersOfTen[m], out remainder);
    return BuildString(quotient, m - 1) + BuildString(remainder, m - 1);
}
```

I've been able to verify the conversion using the examples offered by Will Haley over [here](https://www.willhaley.com/blog/key-space-partitioning/). Now I'm seeking to verify the code to ensure it is doing the exact same conversion as is performed by the Kinesis PutRecord/PutRecords client methods, so I can be 100% confident.

Originally I'd expected to find a function for this in the Kinesis client library, but couldn't find one. I've made this suggestion over on [GitHub](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-client-net/issues/99)

Comment: I found this: https://github.com/mhart/kinesalite/blob/c76689da192ab96c87c5db8f95c1e3fba1985433/db/index.js#L242 - new BigNumber(crypto.createHash('md5').update(partitionKey, 'utf8').digest('hex'), 16) - now I just need to convert it to C#

Comment: And https://github.com/awslabs/kinesis-aggregation/blob/6d26a2d8ba5ce2b77fed578362f54ac8efd654b0/java/KinesisAggregator/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/kinesis/agg/AggRecord.java#L484

Comment: A slight aside to this, using my current implementation of this algorithm with a test set of about 15000 IMEIs shows that an IMEI is an excellent choice of PartitionKey - across 8 shards the divide of IMEIs was: 1920,1951,1956,1867,1906,1959,1913,1930. All nice and even.